# How to connect keyhole to AWS DocumentDB?

Tags: mongodb, performance-testing, aws-documentdb

I want to do some performance testing with on AWS DocumentDB with [keyhole](https://github.com/simagix/keyhole)

What a is valid connection string to connect?

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the go mongodb client I found these steps to get it working:

download AWS RDS certfile:

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
```

and then use this connection string:

```
keyhole -allinfo "mongodb://USER:PASS@my-documentdb-cluster.eu-west-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?ssl=true&sslCertificateAuthorityFile=./rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&retryWrites=false"
```